# Python 3.6 :Query

Tags: python, python-3.x

why is the following?

```
>int(2)
>>2
>
int('2')
>>2
>
int(2.6)
>>2
>
int('2.6')
>>error
```

I cannot understand why the error in the last part?

Comment: I recomend editing the title to be more descriptive. Something like "Error on integer conversion of a string". No need to include the language in the tittle because the tags.

Answer (score 0):

`'2.6'` is not a valid integer.

This works ([see pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/84f0d836-b0b6-4420-9630-b8db2f5de581/?m=Saved%20fiddle)):

```
int(float('2.6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a string containing a float: in Python 3 (not sure about 2) it must be a string of an integer, such as the other cases.

In case you want to read it as an int (of course rounding down or up) you must do something like `int(float(mystring))`